# My code will run in code pen, but not in the browser when I open a .html file?

Tags: javascript

when I run this code in codepen it works fine.

But when I open it through a .html file it doesn't work.

When I opened the developer tool it had an error with the jQuery.

I am new at javascript so I'm not sure what is wrong here. Any help is appreciated.

It's definitely the JQuery that is getting me in trouble.

My error messages.First one: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND jquery.js Second Error: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined on line 74 which is at the end of the code where my comments are // run nextPrompt function when button is clicked.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Shadows+Into+Light' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<script src="/assets/jquery.js"></script>
<style>
body {
 text-align: center;
 font-family: 'Fjalla One';
 font-size: 20px;
 background: #e6eaf0;
}
button {
  margin: 40px; 
}
input {
  font-size: 24px; 
}
.fill {
 background: white;
 color: red;
 border-bottom: 2px black solid;
 font-family: 'Shadows Into Light'; 
 padding: 0 6px; 
 margin: 4px; 
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="prompt"></div>
<button>Next</button>
<script>
// List of prompts for the user
var prompts = [
    'Type your name',
    'Type an adjective',
    'Type a noun'
   ];
var answers=[];
// Keep track of current prompt we're on
var currentPrompt = 0;
// A function that will call the next prompt
var nextPrompt = function() {
  //if there's no answer in the form
  if (currentPrompt != 0){
    answers.push($('input').val());
  }
    // if there is a next prompt
    if (currentPrompt < prompts.length) {
        // put first prompt in all html elements with class 
        $('.prompt').html(prompts[currentPrompt] +'<br><input type="text">');
        // move the next prompt into variable currentPrompt 
        currentPrompt = currentPrompt + 1;
    }
    //or else if we're at the end of the array
    else {
        // put a new message into the html.
        showFinal();
    }
}
//puts user answers into HTML
var showFinal = function() {
  $('.prompt').html('This is the story of <span class="fill">'+answers[0]+'</span> and the <span class="fill">'+answers[1]+'</span> <span class="fill">'+answers[2]+'</span>.');
  //and then hide the button 
  $('button').hide();
}
// run nextPrompt function when button is clicked
$('button').click(function() {
    nextPrompt();
});
// Show the first prompt as soon as js loads
nextPrompt();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have a source link for <script src="/assets/jquery.js"></script>, if you open the developer console, are you seeing that this asset is being served correctly? If not, you would want to create a sub folder where you are serving your javascript for assets/ and put jquery.js in there and try to load it up again.

Comment: Please post relevant code here (not links), and describe your errors.

Comment: Which is line 74?  What's the error?  What's the other error?  If you want to resolve errors in your code, reading the error messages and examining the code they point to is a *great* start.

Comment: Sorry - New to stack overflow so I didn't format this post correctly. It's really just my jquery asset is not working.

Comment: @RebeccaFionna: Define "not working".  What actual indication of a problem do you have?  Have you looked at the browser's developer console for error messages?

Comment: @David My error messages.First one: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND jquery.js Second Error: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined on line 74 which is at the end of the code where my comments are // run nextPrompt function when button is clicked.

Comment: @RebeccaFionna: Then the file `/assets/jquery.js` couldn't be found.  Double-check the location of that file.

Comment: Seeing as you’re a beginner: in case you’re not serving this file using a http server, but opening it directly in the browser, the url to your jquery asset won’t work because it’s an absolute url, not a relative one, i.e. it’ll look for it on file:///C:\assets\jquery.js for example. You can fix this by using a relative path: drop the first slash (src=“assets/jquery.js”). Once you serve it using a http server an absolute path becomes more useful though, because then the url does not need to change depending on the location of your html file.

Comment: I don't see the tag which says jquery included.?   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: @SouravSachdeva: The first `<script>` element in the code: `<script src="/assets/jquery.js"></script>`

Comment: try to load jQuery from a cdn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you get this error because `<script src="/assets/jquery.js"></script>` is failed to load the jquery. both errors are related to this.

> remove `<script src="/assets/jquery.js"></script>` and add

```
<script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
      integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

> it will load a jquery from cdn.
>   it will removed your error.
>   checkout the refactored code below

```
<head>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Shadows+Into+Light' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<!-- <script src="/assets/jquery.js"></script>   -->
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script><style>
body {
 text-align: center;
 font-family: 'Fjalla One';
 font-size: 20px;
 background: #e6eaf0;
}
button {
  margin: 40px; 
}
input {
  font-size: 24px; 
}
.fill {
 background: white;
 color: red;
 border-bottom: 2px black solid;
 font-family: 'Shadows Into Light'; 
 padding: 0 6px; 
 margin: 4px; 
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="prompt"></div>
<button>Next</button>
<script>
// List of prompts for the user
var prompts = [
    'Type your name',
    'Type an adjective',
    'Type a noun'
   ];
var answers=[];
// Keep track of current prompt we're on
var currentPrompt = 0;
// A function that will call the next prompt
var nextPrompt = function() {
  //if there's no answer in the form
  if (currentPrompt != 0){
    answers.push($('input').val());
  }
    // if there is a next prompt
    if (currentPrompt < prompts.length) {
        // put first prompt in all html elements with class 
        $('.prompt').html(prompts[currentPrompt] +'<br><input type="text">');
        // move the next prompt into variable currentPrompt 
        currentPrompt = currentPrompt + 1;
    }
    //or else if we're at the end of the array
    else {
        // put a new message into the html.
        showFinal();
    }
}
//puts user answers into HTML
var showFinal = function() {
  $('.prompt').html('This is the story of <span class="fill">'+answers[0]+'</span> and the <span class="fill">'+answers[1]+'</span> <span class="fill">'+answers[2]+'</span>.');
  //and then hide the button 
  $('button').hide();
}
// run nextPrompt function when button is clicked
$('button').click(function() {
    nextPrompt();
});
// Show the first prompt as soon as js loads
nextPrompt();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```